# Which rule for numerical integration is more accurate, the Trapezoidal Rule or the Simpson Rule?

Tags: integration, numerical-calculus

> Considering the [Trapezoidal Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) and the [Simpson Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule): Which one is more accurate?

For me, it seems to be the Simpson Rule (because it uses quadratic functions compared to linear functions with the trapezoidal rule), but I recently found statements that it isn't true for all cases (but for the most).

Could anyone explain to my why that is? Maybe there exists a trivial example to show this? How can I then state that simpson rule is "in most cases" more accurate? Just by having made this experience?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error formulas are:
$$
E_T = -\frac{h^2}{12} (b-a)f''(\xi_1)
$$

$$
E_S = -\frac{h^4}{180}(b-a) f''''(\xi_2)
$$

So you can imagine that, even if $f''$ and $f''''$ have similar magnitudes, if $h$ is large the trapezoidal method can perform better. Also, if $f$ is $C^2$ but not $C^4$...

Comment: As an add-on, for wildly oscillating functions you could have $f'''' \gg f''$, which would mean that even for reasonably small values of $h$, the trapezium rule would be more accurate.